# View template compilation in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a frontend app in AngularJS. I am using a lot of custom directives to include templates, f.ex.

```
<body>
    <my-header></my-header>
    <site-information></site-information>
</body>
```

Defined in my angular app:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.directive('myHeader', function() {
    return {
        'restrict': 'E',
        'templateUrl': '/partials/template.html'
    }
});
```

And so on.

However, it could be really useful for me, if a template could include two different parts, or "sub-templates", without doing two more AJAX-requests. In other words, that the template could be "compiled" before being shown.

```
<!-- template.html -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
         {{ content_one }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
         {{ content_two }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Regards, Skovmand.